Консультация по поводу поставки данных в minio
Необходимо загрузить файл формата xlsx с локального хранилище ПК в бакет minio посредством кода Python. Прошу подсказать, где закралась ошибка в написанном ниже коде
import boto3

endpoint_url = 'example'
access_key = 'example'
secret_key = 'example'
bucket_name = 'example'

s3_client = boto3.client(
service_name='s3',
endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
aws_access_key_id=access_key,
aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
)

file_path = r'Users\Desktop\Downloads\file.xlsx'
object_name = 'file.xlsx'

try:
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_data:
s3_client.upload_fileobj(file_data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
except FileNotFoundError:
print(f"file {file_path} not found.")


Ну как минимум отступов не хватает. А почему вы думаете, что в коде ошибка?
